# javascript promise catch confusion

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Check the following code, why the error cannot be caught by promise

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
resolve("ok");
setTimeout(function() { throw new Error('test') }, 0)
});
promise.then(function(value) { console.log(value) }).catch(error=>console.log("got an error"));
```

It won't display got an error. 
However, if I directly use Throw new Error('test'), it will be caught.
Can someone please explain why?

Comment: A promise can **either** resolve or reject. If it's already resolved, that's it - it won't then reject.

Comment: Also you never call reject. But you could do this: `promise.then(function(value) {throw new Error('test')}).then(...).catch(...)`

Comment: @SpiderPig what's the difference between use setTimeout and directly throw new Error that cause setTimeout Error won't be caught?

Comment: @Aurora0001 yes I agree with your point but my question is if you directly use throw new Error(), it will be caught.

Comment: How is the promise supposed to know that the error was thrown? The function you pass into setTimeout is not run by the promise.

Comment: @SpiderPig that's resonable. Thanks. I figured the same reason too but I just want to see if I can have some deep thoughts of what promise is.

Comment: One way to deeply understand how a promise works is to implement your own promises. Here is an example: http://pastebin.com/Z8dh4YhL